# programmatically show SVG tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, svg, tooltip

I have an svg:circle with an svg:title element under it such that the title is displayed as a tooltip for the circle. How can I programmatically (using javascript) show and hide this tooltip?

Comment: You mean without mouse interaction?

Comment: yes, I want to show the tooltip without real mouse interactyion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the title element itself can't be shown programmatically, you'd have to create a `<text>` element and position it appropriately. As text does not have background, you either need to create a `<rect>` as background or use a filter to draw a background. Also, there is currently no reliable cross-browser line wrapping (unless you'd be using an HTML `<foreignObject>`).

So, here's a rough suggestion as a starting point:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
  <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="tooltipBackground">
     <feFlood flood-color="rgba(200,200,200,.5)"/>
     <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>

  <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="100">
    <title>my tooltip</title>
  </circle>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showCircleTooltip(circle) {
      var title = circle.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
      if (title) {
        var tooltip = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","text");
        tooltip.textContent = title.textContent;
        tooltip.setAttribute("filter","url(#tooltipBackground)");
        // We're putting the tooltip at the same place as the circle center.
        // Modify this if you prefer different placement.
        tooltip.setAttribute("x",circle.getAttribute("cx"));
        tooltip.setAttribute("y",circle.getAttribute("cy"));
        var transform = circle.getAttribute("transform");
        if (transform) {
          tooltip.setAttribute("transform",transform);
        }
        circle.parentNode.insertBefore(tooltip, circle.nextSibling);
      }
    }

    showCircleTooltip(document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0])
  </script>
</svg>
```

[Try out on Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/iXtB2wE5).